# Stochastically rounding a float to an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, integer, rounding

I want a function (using Python 3.6+ if it's relevant) that will stochastically round a floating-point number to an integer in the following manner:

Given a real number, `x`, let `a = floor(x)` and let `b = ceil(x)`. Then, write a function `s_int()` that will return `a` with a probability of `b - x` and return `b` with a probability of `x - a`.

For example, `s_int(14.8)` should return `14` 20% of the time, and return `15` for the remaining 80% of the time.

---

Here is my attempt:

```
import math
from random import random

def s_int(x):
    a = math.floor(x)
    return a + ((x - a) > random())
```

It appears to work for all cases I can think of:

```
In [2]: Counter(s_int(14.7) for _ in range(1000000))
Out[2]: Counter({14: 300510, 15: 699490})

In [3]: Counter(s_int(-14.7) for _ in range(1000000))
Out[3]: Counter({-15: 700133, -14: 299867})

In [4]: Counter(s_int(14) for _ in range(1000000))
Out[4]: Counter({14: 1000000})

In [5]: Counter(s_int(-14) for _ in range(1000000))
Out[5]: Counter({-14: 1000000})

In [6]: Counter(s_int(0) for _ in range(1000000))
Out[6]: Counter({0: 1000000})
```

---

Here are my questions:

1. Are there any edge cases I didn't consider that this function doesn't work for?
2. Are there other simpler or more elegant solutions?
3. Can this be made to run faster?

Comment: This is probably better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @XYZT I guess you're right.

Comment: Should that be `return a + ((x - a) >= random())`? `random` includes 0.0 but not 1.0. Python's float has a 52 bit mantissa, so the largest number just under the ceiling would never output the floor with your method. I kinda think you have a 1 in 52 bit bias. If I'm right, your rocket will miss Mars by a fair distance. Of course if you change it, `1.0` will emit `2` every once in awhile. I'm begging off the Mars flight completely.

Comment: @tdelaney: Python does not specify the floating-point format, unless that has changed recently. Many implementations use IEEE-754 binary64. The significand, not mantissa, in that format has 53 bits. 52 are encoded in the primary significand field, and 1 is encoded in the exponent field. For the largest representable number under 1 (call it g), the result produced using `>` would never be the ceiling. However, for ceilings greater than 1, the largest representable number under the ceiling would return the ceiling on occasion, as x-floor(x) is less than g due to the greater ULP at x.

Comment: @tdelaney: `(x - a) > random()` also has the advantage that it'll do the right thing for exact integers: if `x` is an exact integer, `x - a` will be exactly zero, so `(x - a) > random()` will never be true and we'll always "round" to `x` itself. With `>=` in place of `>`, there's a (admittedly tiny) chance that say `x = 14.0` could be rounded up to `15.0`.

Comment: Similarly, for values exactly halfway between two integers, `x - a` will be exactly `0.5`, and modulo any flaws in the underlying PRNG, `random() < x - a` will be true exactly half the time, while `random() <= x - a` will have a slight bias. But from a practical perspective, it doesn't matter: you'd have a very hard time writing a statistical test that reliably distinguished the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think there are no edge cases
2. Try using numpy

```py
import numpy as np
def s_int(x):
    a = np.floor(x)
    b = a + 1
    return (np.random.choice([a, b], p=[b - x, x - a]))
```

3. I think that it's an O(1) operation. Does not go faster.

Comment: `np.floor` does not return an integer, it returns a float.

Comment: Also, it's incredibly slow by a factor of 50

Comment: On my laptop, using timeit + rd.random() for 10^6 samples took 7ms,
 >>> print(timeit.timeit(str(s_int(3 + rd.random())), number=1000000))

Comment: OK, Now I see that you are really looking for speed, no just implementation!